# How to use AdminDirectory in Google App Maker?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I've tried to use the AdminDirectory API in a Server Script of App Maker, but this API isn't available.

The next alternative I've tried is create my own Apps Script Library that use the AdminDirectory API. I've could execute tests witout problems.

Then I've included these library in the my App Maker Project. But when it used it throws an error that says: "AdminDirectory" is not defined.

I believe my last chance is use the UrlFetchApp API for compose the request I need (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users), but I could be hard dealing with composing the request, parsing the response and manage OAuth.

Are there any other alternative?

In https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/server they said "(support for Advanced Google Services is coming in future version)". AdminDirectory is an Advanced Google Service. Anyone known when these will be released?

Thanks in advance,

Ernesto.

Comment: When you signed up for the EAP you should have been added to a Google Group. That is probably the best place to ask.

Comment: Can you please give more details about your use case? Maybe Directory Model will be enough? - https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/directory

Comment: The Directory Model is read only. But I need modify some properties (like phone numbers). But with the Ali's instructions, the AdminDirectory API can be used. Thanks.

Comment: In support to Ali Ibrahim's answer, you may want to check [Admin SDK Directory Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) wherein it was noted that it is an advance service that must be [enabled before use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). Additionally, the Admin SDK must be enabled on your domain, as described in the API's [prerequisites documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites).

Answer (score 0):

For Google Advanced Services, you need to enable them explicitly before you can use them. Go to the "General" tab for Application settings, scroll down, and you should see an option for enabling advanced services.